# Regex for 0 or more of a set where at least one of a subset is mandatory

Tags: regex

I'm using regex in Notepad++ (basically PCRE syntax) to find arbitrary-length runs of a set of characters. However, the run must contain at least one of a subset of those characters.

For example, I would use the set [ABCDEFG] where the string can contain 0 or more of A, B, C, or D, but must contain at least E, F, or G.

Currently I'm using [ABCD]*[EFG][ABCD]* i.e. specifying the optional ones before *and* after the mandatory ones. Is there a more concise way to specify this?
(I'm really using sets of diacritics etc. that are a pain to modify and would like to use them as little as possible... the string be used doesn't render properly below. I could use \x{0000} syntax but that would be very verbose)

`[ּֽׁׂׅ֑ׄ]*[ ִ ֶ ַ ֻ][ּֽׁׂׅ֑ׄ]*`

Comment: Simplest and clearest solution you have.

Comment: @revo - nothing shorter? :-(

Comment: Well, you CAN use look ahead to 'scan' for the existence of items. It's less efficient, but well enough for one time use. `(?=.*[EFG])[ABCDEFG]*`

Comment: `I'm really using sets of diacritics etc` This could be problems, better to show what you're actually doing ... i.e. regex

Answer (score 1):

Shorter and more correct

`[A-G]*[EFG][A-G]*`

Plus, I would bookend with whitespace boundary:

`(?<!\S)[A-G]*[EFG][A-G]*(?!\S)`

**update for the Hebrew char's**

The equivalent literal regex would be

```
[ִֶַֻּֽׁׂ֑ׅׄ]*[ִֶַֻ][ִֶַֻּֽׁׂ֑ׅׄ]*
```

but that doesn't render too well.

The better choice is to convert to Codepoint notation

`[\x{591}\x{5B4}\x{5B6}-\x{5B7}\x{5BB}-\x{5BD}\x{5C1}-\x{5C2}\x{5C4}-\x{5C5}]*[\x{5B4}\x{5B6}-\x{5B7}\x{5BB}][\x{591}\x{5B4}\x{5B6}-\x{5B7}\x{5BB}-\x{5BD}\x{5C1}-\x{5C2}\x{5C4}-\x{5C5}]*`

Expanded

```
 [\x{591}\x{5B4}\x{5B6}-\x{5B7}\x{5BB}-\x{5BD}\x{5C1}-\x{5C2}\x{5C4}-\x{5C5}]* 
 [\x{5B4}\x{5B6}-\x{5B7}\x{5BB}] 
 [\x{591}\x{5B4}\x{5B6}-\x{5B7}\x{5BB}-\x{5BD}\x{5C1}-\x{5C2}\x{5C4}-\x{5C5}]*
```

Comment: thanks. I would use ranges where possible - I just used ABC as a quick example. I'm really trying to elide the double usage of [A-G]. btw, what's the point of using [A-G] and not [A-D]?

Comment: @afuna - Ahh, it's the tricks of the regex trade is why. Whenver you need to validate a single character of a set, you put it in the _middle_ of _all_ allowed optional characters. This way you not only validate the existence of one of a required set, you take along all the allowed as well. It's the absolute fastest way to do it !!

Comment: I think I get your point: that the regex will also pick up multiples instances of the required set. As it happens, in my use case such a circumstance never exists - there will never be a duplicate of a vowel point on a hebrew letter. Did I understand you correctly? (re. the unicode, I had updated my question to mention the \x{} syntax but since I'm constructing many such regexes using \x{} makes it hard find errors.)

Comment: @afuna - Sure, you can use `[ABCD]*[EFG][ABCD]*`, but it's not the same a saying you're searching for a sequence using the set `[ABCDEFG]`.  Also, you may think putting Unicode literals inside classes is easier to maintain, but the truth is what's rendered in the same editor on two different machines could be visually different. If you can get a windows machine, grab **[regexformat8](http://www.regexformat.com)** app and let it do all the management for you. Like check out the UCD interface dialog, especially the _Unique_ and _Custom_ tabs. See screenshots.